# Excel - How to return the 'dimension value' from a dataset with the Nth largest 'metric value'

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a way to return specific text if their corresponding value  found on the same row is the largest, or second largest. I've found solutions online that answer parts of the question, but not all elements.

For example, a max/if formula, and some combinations of vlookup would work if not for the fact the dataset has duplicated text within rows, so the values aren't getting properly summed.

My dataset looks as per the following:

[image: 1]

I'm essentially trying to obtain specific values without pivoting; I want a formula to:

- Scan dimension 1 for the phrase "The first" (so "The second" is omitted)
- Sum all of the "Value" numbers at Dimension 2 of the hierarchy. This would mean that all values are summed into either the "Test 1" or "Test 2" labels of Dimension 2
- Have the label with the highest value returned (note that I'm after the text, so either "Test 1" or "Test 2" - whichever is highest rather than the value)

This is the value that that would be returned (because "Test 1" has the most value from the "The first" group):

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the following:

```
=INDEX( $D$1:$D$100, MATCH( MAX( ($C$1:$C$100=$A$1)*SUMIFS( $F$1:$F$100, $C$1:$C$100, $C$1:$C$100, $D$1:$D$100, $D$1:$D$100)), ($C$1:$C$100=$A$1)*SUMIFS( $F$1:$F$100, $C$1:$C$100, $C$1:$C$100, $D$1:$D$100, $D$1:$D$100), 0))
```

Make the following edits:
If the `MAX` is already calculated (the sample contains *Sum of Value*), replace the `MATCH` lookup_value argument,
`MAX( ($C$1:$C$100=$A$1)*SUMIFS( $F$1:$F$100, $C$1:$C$100, $C$1:$C$100, $D$1:$D$100, $D$1:$D$100))`,
with the address of that cell (e.g. cell address of *79180* in the sample).
$C$1:$C$100 *Dimension 1* data range.
$D$1:$D$100 *Dimension 2* data range.
$F$1:$F$100 *Value* data range.
$A$1 The cell address where the value is of the *Dimension 1* being calculated (e.g. result table row heading cell containing *"The first"*).

**Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make this an array formula.**

To get the second highest *Dimension 2*, use the same formula and in the `MAX` function, zero out the highest *Dimension 2* values using `($D$1:$D$100<>[cell_address_of_above_pasted_formula])*` (also add this to the zeroing in the second `INDEX` argument to get the other largest when there is a tie). So `($C$1:$C$100=$A$1)*SUMIFS...` becomes `($D$1:$D$100<>[cell_address_of_above_pasted_formula])*($C$1:$C$100=$A$1)*SUMIFS...`. As before, if the second highest value has been calculated, instead of this edit use the `MAX` substitution mentioned previously but use a reference to the cell with second largest value.